# jquery recognizing later inserted html

Tags: jquery, html

Hello guys i have this script:

```
function getList(){
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "listaPogovorki.php",
   success: function(msg){
   $("#listaPogovorki").html(msg);
 }});

}

getList();
```

with this i call this php script:

```
<table>
<col id="td1"/>
<col id="td2"/>
<col id="td3"/>
<col id="td4"/>
<tr>
<td >#ID</td>
<td >Pogovorka</td>
<td >Avtor</td>
<td >Izmeni</td>
</tr>
<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  ?>
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['pogovorka'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['avtor'] ?></td>
  <td><img class="editImage" src="images/icon_pencil.png" width="16px" height="16px" alt="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } 
  mysql_close($con);
  ?>

</table>
```

now the problem is that the script doesn't recognize the html returned from the php script so i can't make clicking on the images(from php script) to fire some code. For example if i make:

```
$(".editImage").click ....
```

it wont work.

How can i make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [`live` function](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$('.editImage').live('click', ....);
```

Or use another element as an `event delegate`.

Answer (score 1):

The output is not recognised because the html you have returned is not part of the original dom before the script was called.

[Have a look at bind or live with jquery](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 0):

You could place the `$(".editImage").click` inside the AJAX success callback after updating the DOM with the new HTML or use the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method:

```
$('.editImage').live('click', function() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the .live function is for - it binds even to elements that don't exist yet.

$(".editImage").live("click", function() {});

http://api.jquery.com/live/